# Contextual Filter on View not showing through Panel Pane

Tags: taxonomy-terms, panels, views

I'm having trouble getting the contextual filter on my view to show through a panel pane. I want it to show a list of contacts tagged to a topic. The page that the view pane is on will be for the topic. For example, I have several contacts tagged for 'cats.' If I make a 'cats' page, I want those specific contacts to show up in the view pane. I also want this to work for other topics/tags.

I have set the Views display to show as a content pane. The view also works in the preview but it won't show up on the page. Is there a reason it isn't pulling the argument? How would I get this to work?